# Reduce JSON with JS

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, reduce

I am trying to reduce a JSON array. Inside the array are other object, I am trying to turn the attributes into their own array.

Reduce Function:

```
    // parsed.freight.items is path
    var resultsReduce = parsed.freight.items.reduce(function(prevVal, currVal){
        return prevVal += currVal.item
    },[])
    console.log(resultsReduce); 
    // two items from the array
    // 7205 00000
    console.log(Array.isArray(resultsReduce));
    // false
```

The reduce function is kind of working. It gets both `item` from the `items` array.  However I am having a couple problems.

1) The reduce is not passing back an array. See `isArray` test

2) I am trying to make a function so I can loop through all of the attributes in the array the `qty`, `units`, `weight`, `paint_eligable`. I cannot pass a variable to the `currVal.`*variable here*

Attempting:

```
    var itemAttribute = 'item';
    var resultsReduce = parsed.freight.items.reduce(function(prevVal, currVal){
        // pass param here so I can loop through
        // what I actually want to do it create a function and 
        // loop  through array of attributes
        return prevVal += currVal.itemAttribute
    },[])
```

JSON:

```
var request = {
    "operation":"rate_request",
    "assembled":true,
    "terms":true,
    "subtotal":15000.00,
    "shipping_total":300.00,
    "taxtotal":20.00,
    "allocated_credit":20,
    "accessorials":
    {
        "lift_gate_required":true,
        "residential_delivery":true,
        "custbodylimited_access":false
    },
    "freight":
    {
        "items":
        // array to reduce
        [{
            "item":"7205",
            "qty":10,
            "units":10,
            "weight":"19.0000",
            "paint_eligible":false
        },
        {    "item":"1111",
            "qty":10,
            "units":10,
            "weight":"19.0000",
            "paint_eligible":false
        }],

        "total_items_count":10,
        "total_weight":190.0},
        "from_data":
        {
            "city":"Raleigh",
            "country":"US",
            "zip":"27604"},
            "to_data":
            {
                "city":"Chicago",
                "country":"US",
                "zip":"60605"
            }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you like to get only the value from item in an array? or the sum of the items?

Comment: var key = ['item','qty', 'units','paint_eligible', 'weight'];
var resultsReduce = new Object();

key.forEach(function(item){
    resultsReduce[item] = parsed.freight.items.reduce(function(array, object) {
       return array.concat(object[item]);
    }, []);
})  this is what I ended up going.  Just posting for my notes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for getting an array of items

```
var resultsReduce = parsed.freight.items.reduce(function (array, object) {
    return array.concat(object.item);
}, []);
```

The same with a given key, with bracket notation as [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

> ```
> object.property
> object["property"]
> ```

```
var key = 'item',
    resultsReduce = parsed.freight.items.reduce(function (array, object) {
       return array.concat(object[key]);
    }, []);
```

Comment: Thank you, that does solve my first problem.  I was using `prev, curr.item` or `prev+curr.item` but that was giving me the same results.  But makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: i still do not know, what you want - an array or a single number?

Comment: Sorry, I want an array, the first answer you gave was correct. It give me `[ '7205', '00000' ]`.  This is exactly what I want

Comment: I didn't see update.  You answered my question in total